# how to set images from horizontal scrollview into the viewpager in android?

Tags: android, gridview

i have written a program in which i am displaying a gridview of images and when i click on the image another activity opens which has a viewpager to slide my images and there is also a horizontal scrollview at the bottom of the same page which has the same images which is seen in my gridview , till here everything works fine , and yea all the images are being read from my sdcard
Now when i click on the images inside my horizontal scrollview , the image which is displayed up in my viewpager should change , example , like the gallery of s4 , so i am not getting how to do it , need some help

My Code :Inside my imageview.onclick i have set the current Items position with my viewpager but its not working

```
public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity {

private Utils utils;
private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
LinearLayout myGallery;
ImageView iView;
int i;
String path;
int id;
File[] files;
HorizontalScrollView scrollView;
int position;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    myGallery = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mygallery);
    scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal1);
    scrollView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
    String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/Pictures/raw";
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

    files = targetDirector.listFiles();

    for (File file : files) {

        myGallery.addView(insertPhoto(file.getAbsolutePath()));

    }

    utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());

    Intent i = getIntent();
    position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

    adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this,
            utils.getFilePaths());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // displaying selected image first
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}

private View insertPhoto(final String path) {

    final Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(path, 220, 220);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(250, 250));
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(220, 220));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

    // imageView.setId(i);
    // iView.setId(i);
    // viewPager.setId(i);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(id);

        }

    });

    layout.addView(imageView);

    return layout;
}

public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {

    Bitmap bm = null;

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions final
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    return bm;
}
```

}

any suggestions will be of great help 
Thanking You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in this following code the id is not the same index of the viewpager

```
 imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(id);

    }

});
```

Parhaps you can use an arrayList to put all the images and create the horizontal scrollview and the viewpager according to the arrayList order. So, when you click on the image, you will get the index of the Arraylist, then you pass to the viewpager which will set its current fragment because the order will always be the same.

Comment: yes sir, but can you provide me a solution according to my program ?? and sir i havent used fragmentpageradapter , i have used pageradapter , so no fragments in my program

Comment: No problem, you don't need fragment, although the viewpager is a fragment based. So what you must do is just order the position of the images, u know. I need to put the data into the viewpager and into the horizontal scrollview according to the order of arraylist.