# Stucked in horizontal Image Scrolling

Tags: android, image, android-library, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I am junior android developer and making an android app where user can sell and purchase items.

I am very badly stucked please help.

[Here is the UI i am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3L9Y.jpg)

I am making the horizontal Image scroller here. i have tried it using ImageViews in linear layout, recycler view adapter (using horizontal layout manager) but it doesn't solved my problem.
Basically the images in this image scrolling view are coming from different activities and also from this (Add Product Activity) and user can add images in it from camera or gallery and can also delete it ...
so MY QUESTION IS THAT IS THERE ANY EASIEST APPROACH TO HANDLE IMAGE HORIZONTAL SCROLLING ? IS THERE ANY LIBRARY TO USE SO THAT I CAN EASILY MANAGE IMAGES IN MY HORIZONTAL IMAGE SCROLLING VIEW ? OR ANY APPROACH YOU PREFER PLEASE SHARE WITH ME...........
THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you trying wrong things and you should try using android **ViewPager**
and for your question you should look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040736/how-to-set-images-from-horizontal-scrollview-into-the-viewpager-in-android)  and here is sample code for View Page from [This Link](http://life-optimized.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-create-image-viewer-using.html)

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >  

      <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">  

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/_linearLayout"  
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
          android:orientation="horizontal">  

        </LinearLayout>  

      </HorizontalScrollView>  

      <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/_viewPager"  
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
          android:background="#000000"  
          android:visibility="gone" />  

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**cell.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
      android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"   
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
      android:orientation="vertical" >   

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/_image"   
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>   

   <TextView android:id="@+id/_imageName"   
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>   

  </LinearLayout>
```

**Page Adapter CLass**

```
import android.app.Activity;  
 import android.os.Parcelable;  
 import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;  
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;  
 import android.view.View;  
 import android.widget.ImageView;  

 public class GalleryPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {  

      private Activity activity;  
      private int[] drawableIDs;  

      public GalleryPagerAdapter(Activity activity,int[] drawableIDs){  

           this.activity = activity;  
           this.drawableIDs = drawableIDs;  
      }  

   @Override  
   public int getCount() {  
       return drawableIDs.length;  
   }  

      /**  
       * Create the page for the given position. The adapter is responsible  
       * for adding the view to the container given here, although it only  
       * must ensure this is done by the time it returns from  
       * {@link #finishUpdate()}.  
       *  
       * @param container The containing View in which the page will be shown.  
       * @param position The page position to be instantiated.  
       * @return Returns an Object representing the new page. This does not  
       * need to be a View, but can be some other container of the page.  
       */  
   @Override  
   public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {  

       ImageView imageView = new ImageView(activity);  

       imageView.setBackgroundResource(drawableIDs[position]);  

       ((ViewPager) collection).addView(imageView,0);  

       return imageView;  
   }  

      /**  
       * Remove a page for the given position. The adapter is responsible  
       * for removing the view from its container, although it only must ensure  
       * this is done by the time it returns from {@link #finishUpdate()}.  
       *  
       * @param container The containing View from which the page will be removed.  
       * @param position The page position to be removed.  
       * @param object The same object that was returned by  
       * {@link #instantiateItem(View, int)}.  
       */  
   @Override  
   public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {  
       ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((ImageView) view);  
   }  

   @Override  
   public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {  
       return view==((ImageView)object);  
   }  

      /**  
       * Called when the a change in the shown pages has been completed. At this  
       * point you must ensure that all of the pages have actually been added or  
       * removed from the container as appropriate.  
       * @param container The containing View which is displaying this adapter's  
       * page views.  
       */  
   @Override  
   public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {}  

   @Override  
   public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {}  

   @Override  
   public Parcelable saveState() {  
       return null;  
   }  

   @Override  
   public void startUpdate(View arg0) {}  
 }
```

**And finally, the activity**

```
 import android.app.Activity;  
 import android.os.Bundle;  
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;  
 import android.view.View;  
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
 import android.widget.ImageView;  
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;  
 import android.widget.TextView;  

 public class TestingActivity extends Activity {  

      // mainLayout is the child of the HorizontalScrollView ...  
      private LinearLayout mainLayout;  

      // this is an array that holds the IDs of the drawables ...  
      private int[] images = {R.drawable.dd1, R.drawable.dd2, 
      R.drawable.dd3, R.drawable.dd4, R.drawable.dd5, R.drawable.dd6, R.drawable.dd7};  

      private View cell;  
      private TextView text;  

      private ViewPager viewPager;  

      @Override  
      public void onBackPressed() {  

           if(viewPager != null && viewPager.isShown()){  

                viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
           }  
           else{  

                super.onBackPressed();  
           }  
      }  

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
   @Override  
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {  
     super.onCreate(icicle);  

     setContentView(R.layout.main);  

     viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id._viewPager);  

     mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id._linearLayout);  

     for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {  

          cell = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cell, null);  

          final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cell.findViewById(R.id._image);  
          imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

                     @Override  
                     public void onClick(View v) {  

                          viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                          viewPager.setAdapter
                          (new GalleryPagerAdapter(TestingActivity.this, images));  
                          viewPager.setCurrentItem(v.getId());  
                     }  
                });  

          imageView.setId(i);  

          text = (TextView) cell.findViewById(R.id._imageName);  

          imageView.setImageResource(images[i]);  
          text.setText("Image#"+(i+1));  

          mainLayout.addView(cell);  
       }  
   }  
 }
```

If you don't want to use ViewPager then you should try RecyclerView in Horizontal way and with RecyclerView you can add and delete views in realtime with automatic position check [this tutorial for more help](http://www.androhub.com/android-staggered-and-horizontal-recyclerview/)

Comment: Thank you very much it is the best way to view images... i can set images easily but how can i delete any of the added image and remaining images will dynamically change their positions

Comment: @tahanaqvi Accept Answer if it helps.Please refer google for more help btw its not hard to achieve

Comment: it doesnt helped yet i m trying ...i have searched and having issue in it. can u give me link of any tutorial or something else in which images are added and deleted from camera or gallery in a horizontal scrollview

Comment: and sorry but my client said that i dont have to view image in a view pager i just have to show them horizontally and delete them without viewing on full screen. so my main problem is in handling images that are coming from gallery and camera that how to add then delete any item and re-position other items

Comment: @tahanaqvi then you should try `recyclerview` which help you in achieve your task without viewpager Check Updated answer for Details